# Center of star configuration

Tags: alternator

[image]is there any reason to connect the center of winding to the ground of 3 phase rectifier? Or shouldn't I do that?

Comment: please add a schematic diagram ... there is a button for that when you edit your post

Comment: Do not connect the star center to the DC side of the rectifier. If the star is unbalanced for some reason (e.g. one diode broken), that would blow up all the other diodes in the rectifier, and fry the rest of the circuit also.

Comment: that appears to be a thyristor bridge,  is that significant?

Answer (score 1):

**That's not ground!**  don't connect it.

That's negative, and will bave a voltage less than neutral by the same measure that the positive end of the rectifier is above neutral.

If you make that connection you short-circuit half the bridge, EG: trace the path from U1 through the rectifier VU and back through the proposed connection to the other end of U1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it is thyristor rectifier, but I wasn't able to find diode one.